# problem with viewing and exporting persian characters stored in my sql using navicat or powerbi

Tags: mysql, powerbi, navicat, farsi

Recently, my company granted me READ access to one of our MySQL databases. They instructed me to use 'utf8' for the client character set and '65001' for encoding. After using this setting, I discovered that the database's character set is 'latin1' and the collation is 'latin1_swedish_ci.' Now, how can I view my Persian characters or export them with Navicat or Power BI correctly?

I've tried using Navicat and Power BI and attempted to change the font and other settings, but nothing seems to work. and the resualt is something like this ÙØ±ÙˆØ´
Every solution I've come across involves changing the database's character set, but with my read-only access, I can't do that. Our company's software works with the database without any issues, so altering anything on the database is not an option.

Comment: You probably need to extract the data as latin1 and then use an external script to convert latin1 to utf8 on byte level. Navicat and powerbi cannot do this - they were prepared to use strings with properly encoded characters.

Comment: If you just want the characters to be correctly encoded when connected with charset utf8mb4, you can `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(col_name) USING utf8mb4) AS col_name FROM ...`.

Comment: not sure if this will work, in PowerQuery you could try `= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "TestColumn", each Text.FromBinary(Text.ToBinary([yourColumn], 65001), TextEncoding.Utf8))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Window's `cmd`, use this:

```
chcp 65001
```

As for the "client" -- what are you using?  PHP?  Perl?  Java?  C++?  That is where "UTF-8" should be specified.

When connecting to MySQL (from the client), specify, well, your instructions were incomplete.  Suggest connecting with `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`; it might work best.

If `وش` would be reasonable for part of that Mojibake you provided, then see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for more discussion.

I'll need more details from you if those are not sufficient.